# Pass String Variable Through As Python Attribute

Tags: python

If I have python...

```
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

How can I get it to work with...

```
myvar = 'get'
r = requests.myvar('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

I.e. parse the string through as a command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
myvar = 'get'
getattr(requests, myvar)('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

Comment: Ah thank you, attribute, not operator! I'll update the question and mark it as correct when I'm allowed.

Comment: Would `r = self.requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))` be `getattr(self, requests, myvar)('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))`?

Comment: @square_eyes  Just replace `getattr(self, requests, myvar)` with `getattr(self.requests, myvar)` and the rest is identical.

Comment: Thanks again. Very quick and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`getattr()` will work perfectly, but it also means that a user can specify whatever method they choose, possibly ones you don't want to expose. Another approach would be:

```
{
    "get": requests.get,
    "post": requests.post, # maybe
    # etc
}[myvar]('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getattr,
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr

```
r = getattr(requests, myvar)('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

Answer (score 0):

OK off the top of my head

```
myvar = 'get'
getattr(requests, myvar)('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
```